# System.diagnostics.process process is not working on IIS after hosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to install .exe from web application. when i run the application locally(from asp development server) it is installing properly. But when i hosted on IIS it is not working.

I had written this code on Page_load method in asp.net page

//Want to install Test.msi on client machine.

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/NewFolder1/Test.msi");//NewFolder1 is on server

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('"+filepath+"')", true);
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
// startInfo.Arguments = "/K msiexec.exe /i \"" + @"D:\Datta\CrispDoxCompression.msi" + "\" /quite /qn";
startInfo.Arguments = "/K msiexec.exe /i \"" + filepath + "\" /qn";
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: This launches (or at least tries to) the installer on the *web server*. Not on the machine on which someone's browser is currently running. If that was your expectation, that's not what happens (but, of course, when both machines are the same machine, when it's the development server, it may appear to work). Random websites on the internet aren't allowed to launch silent installs through people's browsers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is it possible to install activex control silently(Without User intervention)                                                                        --when both machines are the same machine the code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I run the application locally (from asp development server) it is installing properly

Of course, because then the server and the client are the same machine. You're starting a process on the server, which also happens to be the client, but in production, this isn't the case.

If you want users to install an application on their machine, then create a page on your site that shows them how to do so, including a link where they can download the installer.

You are **not** able to automatically install software from a website on a client's machine, let alone silently.

Sit down a minute and think about the implications if what you were asking for were actually possible. Barring browser (plugin) exploits, the days when that was possible are long gone.

If you are running this site in a controlled environment, then perhaps you can get your system administrators to deploy this installer for certain user groups on your domain.